# python3 Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having an issue using python on my Mac. Running `which python` yields:

```
/anaconda3/bin/python3
```

Yet when I then run `$ python3` I receive the following error message:

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007ffff21b23c0 (most recent call first):
Abort trap: 6
```

I am not deeply familiar with how python installations work so if there are things I can do to further explain the issue please let me know.

I am trying to get back to developing an app I am working on but currently I am at a complete roadblock and unable to use python at all.

Help much appreciated! Thank you!